# Not a managed type creating and composite id with @IdClass

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to create two class with spring in order to have IdClass.
I tried this:

```
import java.persistence.*;

public class InfosId extends Serializable {

    private String name;

    private String age;

    public Infos() { }

    public Infos(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }

    public Infos(String name, String age) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name= name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }

    public String getAge() { return age; }

    public void setAge(String age) { this.age= age;}

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return (this == other) ||  this.name.equals( ((Infos) other).name  );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode();
    }

}
```

and I want to use the first class InfosId as attribute of the class below:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(InfosId.class)
@Table(name = "infos")
@EntityListeners(Infos .class)
public class Infos {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "age")
    private String age;

    public Infos() { }

    public Infos(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }

    public Infos(String name, String age) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name= name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }

    public String getAge() { return age; }

    public void setAge(String age) { this.age= age;}    
}
```

unfortunately, I obtain when I execute my code this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'apiInController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'accessPointService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accessPointService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'consumer'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'consumerService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'infosRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'infosRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.test.datalake.model.entity.infosId
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at com.test.datalake.ApiInApplication.main(ApiInApplication.java:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accessPointService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'consumer'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'consumerService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'infosRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'infosRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.test.model.entity.InfosId
```

do you have any idea why I get the exception?

I tried to follow instruction from this post :   http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/01/jpa-idclass-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my fault, I was giving the class InfosId despite Infos inside my class InfosRepository. I now have:

```
@Repository
public interface InfoRepository extends JpaRepository<Infos, String> {

}
```

and not

```
@Repository
public interface InfoRepository extends JpaRepository<InfosID, String> {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the given example it seems like you are missing 2 things:

1. @IdClass(InfosId.class) instead of @IdClass(InfosId)
2. Missing Serializable in the id class

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you for your answer unfortunately it was just a mistake on my post but not on my code. I have edited my post

Answer (score 0):

According hibernate documentation you have to add getId and setId methods.

```
    public InfosId getId() {
        return new InfosId (
            name, age
        );
    }

    public void setId(InfosId id) {
        this.name= id.getName();
        this.age = id.getAge();
    }
```

Something like this:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(InfosId.class)
@Table(name = "infos")
@EntityListeners(Infos .class)
public class Infos {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "age")
    private String age;

    public Infos() { }

    public Infos(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }

    public Infos(String name, String age) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name= name;
    }

    public InfosId getId() {
        return new InfosId (
            name, age
        );
    }

    public void setId(InfosId id) {
        this.name= id.getName();
        this.age = id.getAge();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }

    public String getAge() { return age; }

    public void setAge(String age) { this.age= age;}    
}
```

documentation http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite-nonaggregated